# How can I set right height for the elements?

Tags: html, css

I set `height` = 100% for `html` and `body`, but I see the vertical scroll. How can I fit my `body` without the scroll?

Also, I placed into the `body` two `div` elements with `height` = `50%`, but I see the bottom border is out of the area of my `body`. Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

```css
html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      border-color: #00cc00;
      border-width: thin;
      border-style: solid;
      min-height: 100%;
    }

    .div1 {
      border-color: #0099ff;
      border-width: thin;
      border-style: solid;
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Sandbox</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Border size is making the problems. I have removed border from the `div1` and added `background-color`. You will not see div going out.
Also, if you remove the border style from body and add `margin:0;` and `padding:0;` then you won't see scrollbar. (I am keeping the border to see the fix for first problem)

See the Snippet below:

```css
html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }

    body {
      border-color: #00cc00;
      border-width: thin;
      border-style: solid;
      min-height: 100%;
    }

    .div1 {
      background-color:red;
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    .div2{
    background-color: pink;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Sandbox</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div1 div2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Box Sizing**

If you need borders then you can use `box-sizing:border-box` style for div.

See the Snippet below: (Remove the `margin-bottom:10px;` from body so you won't see scrollbar)

```css
html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }

    body {
      border-color: #00cc00;
      border-width: thin;
      border-style: solid;
      min-height: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin-bottom:10px;
    }

    .div1 {
      border-color: #0099ff;
      border-width: thin;
      border-style: solid;
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Sandbox</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Side scroll appears due to default margins of body element.
To avoid this you need to set `margin: 0;` for body.
Also it may happen because of `box-sizing` attribute. Just setting `box-sizing: border-box;` makes div size 50% including borders thickness

```css
html, body {
      height: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      border-color: #00cc00;
      margin: 0;
      border-width: thin;
      border-style: solid;
      min-height: 100%;
    }

    .div1 {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-color: #0099ff;
      border-width: thin;
      border-style: solid;
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Sandbox</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is being caused by the pixel-width of the borders that you are including on the different elements. By using the box-sizing property, you can tell the browser that it needs to factor in the border width of elements when doing percentage calculations, such as the height and width.

You can also hide the vertical scrollbar by using `overflow-y: hidden;`.

Here is the minimum code that you need to achieve this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sandbox</title>
<style>
html, body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
body {
  border: 1px solid #00cc00;
}
.div1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #0099ff;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
   HTML { height:100%; }
body { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; 
   
        border-color: #00cc00;

     
    }

    .div1 {
      border-color: #0099ff;
      border-width: thin;
      border-style: solid;
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Sandbox</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or you can change the code "HTML { height:100vh; } body {height: 100vh; min-height: 100vh; position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; }"